# Need to double sprintf formats and returns too long string

Tags: c++, arduino

(This is a modified paste from : https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=544603.msg3711704)

First, here is my code:

```
//#include <RCSwitch.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

#define deviceSerial 1

//RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

int button1 = PB2;
int button2 = PB1;
int button3 = PB0;

int radio = PB3;
int keepalive = PB4;

int i = 0;

unsigned long long intToBin(unsigned int k) {
    return (k == 0 || k == 1 ? k : ((k % 2) + 10 * intToBin(k / 2)));
}

unsigned int nextCode(){
  // Get current occurrence
  int occurrence = getOccurrence();
  // Increment occurrence
  // Commented out to preserve EEPROM at the moment
  //incrementOccurrence();
  *censored code*
  return *censored code but returns an int*
}

int getOccurrence(){
  return (EEPROM.read(0) + EEPROM.read(1) + EEPROM.read(2) + EEPROM.read(3));
}

void incrementOccurrence(){
  int occurrence = getOccurrence() + 1;
  if(occurrence >= 1020){
    //reset
    EEPROM.write(0, 1);
    EEPROM.write(1, 0);
    EEPROM.write(2, 0);
    EEPROM.write(3, 0);
  }
  else if (occurrence >= 765){
    EEPROM.write(0, 255);
    EEPROM.write(1, 255);
    EEPROM.write(2, 255);
    EEPROM.write(3, occurrence - 765);
  }
  else if (occurrence >= 510){
    EEPROM.write(0, 255);
    EEPROM.write(1, 255);
    EEPROM.write(2, occurrence - 510);
    EEPROM.write(3, 0);
  }
  else if (occurrence >= 255){
    EEPROM.write(0, 255);
    EEPROM.write(1, occurrence - 255);
    EEPROM.write(2, 0);
    EEPROM.write(3, 0);
  }
  else {
    EEPROM.write(0, occurrence);
    EEPROM.write(1, 0);
    EEPROM.write(2, 0);
    EEPROM.write(3, 0);
  }
}

void transmit(int button){
  char message[33];
  sprintf(message, "%014lu%lu%016lu%lu%02lu", intToBin(deviceSerial), intToBin(nextCode()), intToBin(button)); <---------------
  //mySwitch.send(message);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(keepalive, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(keepalive, HIGH);

  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);

  //mySwitch.enableTransmit(radio);

  if(digitalRead(button1) == 1){
    transmit(1);
  }
  if(digitalRead(button2) == 1){
    transmit(2);
  }
  if(digitalRead(button3) == 1){
    transmit(3);
  }

  // Self shutdown
  digitalWrite(PB4, LOW);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Currently outputs (separated values):

```
0000000000000100000001011010010010 (00000000000001 0000000101101001 0010)
```

Where it should be (separated values):

```
00000000000001000000010110100110 (00000000000001 0000000101101001 10)
```

My problem resides where I'm trying to retrieve all the variables to send the message.

- Why do I need to double the `%lu`?
- How come the output string is 34 chars when I declared 33 (32 + \0)? Last long is 4 instead of two (0010 instead of 10)

The weird thing is:

```
sprintf(message, "%016lu", intToBin(nextCode())); // Works correctly
sprintf(message, "%014lu", intToBin(deviceSerial)); // Works correctly
sprintf(message, "%02lu", intToBin(button)); //Works correctly
```

Comment: Please note that the formatting width specifier does not truncate the data if it is too long for the field width. I don't know what you are asking - you provide 5 format specifiers but only 3 arguments.

Comment: I assume you're talking about last part of the message var being too long. Yes, all vars are controlled (deviceSerial hardcoded never over 16383 (14 bits), code is int so 16 bits (on Arduino) and button is int but won't get higher than 3 so 2 bits. As I said, sprintf(message, "%02lu", intToBin(button)); returns expected string.

Comment: The individual calls "work" because 4 of the 8 bytes of the argument are ignored by the `%lu` format spec. But when you try to do three in the same call, the extra size causes the `%lu` to misalign where it is reading from. The two extra `%lu` are a "trick" to use the other 4 bytes of the first two arguments, and each is outputting a single `0` resulting in the output having 2 more digits than you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is

```
unsigned long long intToBin(unsigned int k)
```

but your format specifiers are `%lu`. The dummy `%lu` "works" by aligning the data.

Please use the correct format specifier `%llu`.

**EDIT:** `%llu` is not supported. You successfully used:

```
sprintf(message, "%016lu", intToBin(nextCode())); // Works correctly
sprintf(message, "%014lu", intToBin(deviceSerial)); // Works correctly
sprintf(message, "%02lu", intToBin(button)); //Works correctly
```

Suggested fix to build `message`:

```
int len;
len  = sprintf(message,       "%016lu", intToBin(nextCode()));
len += sprintf(message + len, "%014lu", intToBin(deviceSerial));
       sprintf(message + len, "%02lu",  intToBin(button));
```

Comment: If `%llu` is not supported on Arduino, you could change `intToBin` so it writes 0s and 1s directly to a string.